# WSO2 ESB proxy service Escaping JSON payload when passing to jaggery js

Tags: wso2, jaggery-js, wso2-esb

I am POSTing to a ESB (4.6.0) proxy service with a JSON payload.  This is a pass through proxy service that routes to a jaggery JS app.  The jaggery app is trying to access the JSON from the payload, but it is unable to because the JSON strings are escaped.

Here are the request headers (from web --> ESB):

```
POST /services/testJaggPS HTTP/1.1
Host: pb-dvwa8:7280
Content-Length: 29
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

{
  "PARAM": "hello world" 
}
```

And here is the JSON response from the jaggery app:

```
{"RESPONSE" : {"test" : "hi", "PARAM" : null, "content" : "{\n \"PARAM\" : \"HELLO WORLD\" \n}"}}
```

Note that "content" (variable that stores JSON payload from web) is being escaped.

I have looked into message builders/formatters, but it has not solved this issue.  Here is my current proxy service (probably don't need all of the message builders):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="testJaggPS"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <target endpoint="jaggRouter">
      <inSequence>
         <builder>
            <messageBuilder contentType="application/xml"
                            class="org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder"
                            formatterClass="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter"/>
            <messageBuilder contentType="application/xop+xml"
                            class="org.apache.axis2.builder.MTOMBuilder"/>
            <messageBuilder contentType="multipart/related"
                            class="org.apache.axis2.builder.MIMEBuilder"/>
            <messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                            class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBuilder"
                            formatterClass="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter"/>
            <messageBuilder contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                            class="org.apache.axis2.builder.XFormURLEncodedBuilder"
                            formatterClass="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.XFormURLEncodedFormatter"/>
            <messageBuilder contentType="text/xml"
                            class="org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder"
                            formatterClass="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
            <messageBuilder contentType="application/soap+xml"
                            class="org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder"
                            formatterClass="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
            <messageBuilder contentType="application/json/badgerfish"
                            class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBadgerfishOMBuilder"/>
         </builder>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="contentType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="contentType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

And here is my jaggery code:

> ```
> <%
> // load core files
> response.contentType = 'application/json';
>
> var url = request.getRequestURL();
> var theContent = request.getContent();  
>  // note null 'PARAM' and escaped 'content'    
> response.content = {"RESPONSE" : {
>   "test" : "hi",
>     "PARAM" : theContent.PARAM,
>     "content" : theContent
> }};
>
> %>
> ```

Comment: This turned out not to be an issue due to JSON.parse() defined in jaggery.js However, I would still like to know if there is a better way of doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with Jaggery's automatic JSON parsing when you have additional stuff in the Content-Type header such as character encoding etc. It was fixed in master branch.

But, if you are trying with an earlier version, you will have to manually parse the content using **JSON.parse()**. i.e. replace your

```
var theContent = request.getContent();
```

line in Jaggery file, with

```
var theContent = JSON.parse(request.getContent());
```